# Facebook SDK error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I recently upgraded to the latest version of the facebook SDK and I'm having issues logging users in.  I generate the login link just fine, but when facebook sends the user back to my site with the token, I get this error:

fb sdk error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.

I tried to do some trouble shooting. I printed out everything in the session data and everything in the GET request.  I see that the GET has a state parameter and the session data has a FBRLH_state parameter. They both have the same value.  So how is it telling me that the parameter is missing?

I've tried some suggestions I've seen on other questions (ie, starting the session), but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I'm using the php-graph-sdk-5.5.  My facebook connect file is below

```
    if(!class_exists('facebook')){
    class facebook{

        private $db = null;
        private $fb = null;
        private $token = null;
        private $DEV = null;
        private $sdk_error = null;
        private $api_error = null;
        private $verbose = false;
        private $graph_user = null;
        private $db_helper = null;
        private $errors = null;

        public function __construct($db,
                                    $fb_id = FB_APP_ID,
                                    $fb_secret = FB_APP_SECRET,
                                    $fb_version = FB_DEFAULT_GRAPH_VERSION){
            if($this->verbose) echo '<pre>';
            if($this->verbose) echo 'starting construction'.PHP_EOL;
            $this->db = $db;
            if(!$this->fb){
                $this->log[] = 'no connect found. building..'.PHP_EOL;

                $this->fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
                            'app_id' => $fb_id,
                            'app_secret' => $fb_secret,

                            'default_graph_version' => $fb_version));
                if(!$this->fb){
                    die('facebook initialization failure');
                }
                $this->log[] = 'finished building new connection'.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }

        public function get_login_url($callback_uri, $permissions = ['email','user_birthday']){

            global $_DEV,$_config;
            $helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

            $callback_host = ($_DEV ? $_config['dev_domain'] : $_config['live_domain']);
            $callback_url = 'https://'.$callback_host.$callback_uri;
            return $helper->getLoginUrl($callback_url, $permissions);
        }

        public function catch_token(){
            if($this->token){
                $this->log[] = 'already have token.'.PHP_EOL;

                return $this->token;
            } else if(!$this->fb){
                $this->log[] = $this->error[] = 'no facebook connection in catch token()';

            }

            $this->log[] = 'starting catch token routine.'.PHP_EOL;
            //$_SESSION['state']=$_GET['state'];
            echo '<pre>' . var_export($_SESSION, true) . '</pre>';
                        echo '<BR><BR><pre>' . var_export($_GET, true) . '</pre>';
                $helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

                $this->token = $helper->getAccessToken();

                $this->log[] = 'caught token: '.$this->token;
                $string_token = $this->token.PHP_EOL;
                //die($string_token);
            try {

                $helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

                $this->token = $helper->getAccessToken();

                $this->log[] = 'caught token: '.$this->token;
                $string_token = $this->token.PHP_EOL;

                return $this->user_flush();
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                // When Graph returns an error
                $this->log[] = $this->errors[] = 'fb api error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                return null;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                // When validation fails or other local issues
                $this->log[] = $this->errors[] = 'fb sdk error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                return null;
            } catch(Exception $e){
                $this->log[] = $this->errors[] = 'unknown error: '.$e->getMessage();
                return null;
            }
        }

        public function get_token(){
            $this->log[] = 'get token called.'.PHP_EOL;
            if($this->token){
                $this->log[] = 'token found in object'.PHP_EOL;
                //echo '<pre>';
                //die(debug_print_backtrace());
                return $this->token;
            } else {
                $this->log[] = $this->errors[] = 'token not found in object.'.PHP_EOL;
                return null;
            }
        }

        public function get_user($override = false){
            $fields = array(
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'id',
                'picture',
                'birthday',
                'gender',);
            $fields = implode(',',$fields);
            if($this->graph_user === null){
                if($this->fb && $this->get_token()){
                    try {
                      // Returns a Facebook\FacebookResponse object
                      $resp_url = '/me?fields='.$fields.'&debug=all';
                      $this->log[] = $resp_url;
                      $response = $this->fb->get($resp_url, $this->get_token());
                      $this->graph_user = $response->getGraphUser();
                      return $this->graph_user;
                    } 
                    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                        // When Graph returns an error
                        $this->api_error = 'fb api error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                        $this->errors[] = $this->api_error;
                        return null;
                    }
                    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                        // When validation fails or other local issues
                        $this->sdk_error = 'fb sdk error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                        $this->errors[] = $this->sdk_error;
                        return null;
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->sdk_error = "get_user(): fb connection or token not set. are you logged in?";
                    $this->errors[] = $this->sdk_error;
                    //echo '<pre>';
                    //debug_print_backtrace();
                    //die('token: '.$this->token);
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                $this->sdk_error = "get_user(): graph_user already set";
                $this->errors[] = $this->sdk_error;
                return $this->graph_user;
            }

        }

        public function get_user_first_name(){
            return $this->get_user()['first_name'];
        }
        public function get_user_last_name(){
            return $this->get_user()['last_name'];
        }
        public function get_user_id(){
            return $this->get_user()['id'];
        }
        public function get_user_email(){
            return $this->get_user()['email'];
        }
        public function get_user_picture(){
            return $this->get_user()['picture']['url'];
        }
        public function get_user_birthday(){
            return $this->get_user()['birthday'];
        }

        public function user_flush(){
            //this is the command function.
            //  runs the basic functionality of this class
            //  by adding this user to the database if they're not there
            //      and logging them in if they are.
            $this->graph_user = $this->get_user();
            //$this->log['graph_user_at_user_flush'] = $this->graph_user;
            $this->build_user();
            $this->log['GRAPH_USER'] = $this->get_user();
            $this->log['user_input_array@user_flush'] = $this->user_input;
            if($return = $this->user->fb_register()){
                //die(print_r(debug_backtrace(),true));
                //$this->log['success return'] = '. '.$return;
                return $return;
            } else {
                //die('<pre>'.print_r(debug_backtrace(),true));
                $this->log['fb_register_fail'] = array('fb_register() (also login) failed.',$this->user->get_errors());
                return null;
            }
        }

        public function build_user(){

            $this->user_input['first_name'] = $this->get_user_first_name();
            //$this->user_input['last_name'] = $this->get_user_last_name();
            $this->user_input['facebook_id'] = $this->get_user_id();
            $this->user_input['email'] = $this->get_user_email();
            $this->user_input['image_url'] = $this->get_user_picture();
            $this->user_input['birthday'] = $this->get_user_birthday();
            if($this->verbose) 
                print_r($this->user_input);
            $this->user = new user($this->user_input,$this->db);
        }

        public function logout(){
            unset($_SESSION['fb_id']);
            unset($this->token);
            unset($this->fb);
        }

        public function get_errors(){
            return array_unique($this->errors);
        }
        public function get_log(){
            return array_unique($this->log);
        }
    }
}


//finally, create the connection.
if(!isset($fb))
    $fb = new facebook($db);
```

Comment: I guess it might have something to do with that you are going through the routine of getRedirectLoginHelper and $helper->getAccessToken() twice for some bizarre reason ...

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! That did the trick. If you submit it as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> fb sdk error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.

It has something to do with that you are going through the routine of calling getRedirectLoginHelper and $helper->getAccessToken() twice - once "on their own", and then again inside a try-catch block (copy&paste mistake, or unfortunate debug attempt maybe?)

I'm a bit too lazy to go check the SDK source right now, but I think it deliberately unsets the state parameter inside the session after the code was exchanged for a token, as part of making the whole process more secure - so that when you call getAccessToken a second time, it fails.

Comment: I have to get the same error, Also check not duplicate code as like "getAccessToken". can you please help me. My demo URL is here http://demo.sigzen.net/fb-login/v5/

Answer (score 10):

This might be kinda late but I hope it helps others.

I had this problem for a while and I've searched around and have seen a lot of different solutions, many of which disable the CSRF check. So after everything I've read, this is what worked for me.

For what I understand, you get this error when your redirect URL doesn't match the one you have setup on your app settings so my issue was fixed every easily but I have also seen people have issues by not having their session started properly, so I will cover both issues.

**Step 1: Ensure your session has started when it needs to.**

**for example: fb-config.php**

```
session_start();
include_once 'path/to/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'your_app_id',
    'app_secret' => 'your_secret_app_id',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
```

if your facebook callback code is on another file aside from the config, then start the session on that file too.

**for example: fb-callback.php**

```
session_start();
include_once 'path/to/fb-config.php';

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo "Response Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "SDK Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

/** THE REST OF YOUR CALLBACK CODE **/
```

Now, what solved my actual issue.

**Step 3: Set up your redirect URL in your app settings.**

In your Facebook Login app settings, go to the **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** where you should have added the url that points to your fb-callback.php file.

```
http://example.com/fb-callback.php

AND ALSO

http://www.example.com/fb-callback.php
```

then setup your redirect url as follows.

```
$redirectURL = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/fb-callback.php";
$permissions = ['email'];
$fLoginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $permissions);
```

Why both with and without www and why use SERVER_NAME?

because your **Valid OAuth redirect URI** needs to match your redirect url in your code and if in you app settings you only set your OAuth redirect as http://example.com/fb-callback.php and set up your $redirectURL as http://example.com/fb-bacllback.php to make it match but the user entered your site as http://www.example.com then the user will get the **Facebook SDK error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param “state” missing from persistent data** because the URL the user is at, doesn't EXACTLY match what you have setup. Why? I have no freaking idea.

My approach makes it so if the user enters your site as http://example.com or http://www.example.com, it will always match what you setup in your app settings. why? because $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] will return the domain with or without the www depending on how the user entered the url in the browser.

This are my findings and this is about the only thing that worked for me without removing the CSRF check and so far, no issues.

I hope this helps.

Comment: it helped really, In my case, missing session start line

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still with this proglem just add a `session_start()` at the begining of the callback file.

Answer (score 2):

Well I faced the same error today and I got my solution from [tutorials point](http://tutorialspots.com/facebook-graph-api-how-to-fix-error-cross-site-request-forgery-validation-failed-required-param-state-missing-4605.html)

In your callback file, just add this line and you're good to go

```php
if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
    $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $_GET['state']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but I faced this error, and I don't believe my solution was covered in the above responses, so here it goes:

One reason this error may arise is if you submit the same URL login request to Facebook more than once. For example, a user may impatiently click on a login button more than once, triggering multiple submissions of the URL. In my case, the solution was to intercept all clicks after the first with a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

Change version to v2.10 Check  graph you are using in configuration php file
// Call Facebook API

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Both the things didn't work for me for v14.

Adding that small code just before `$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();` worked.

Here's the code that actually worked -

```
$helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $_GET['state']);
```

Answer (score -2):

Still got this error after clicking login..

> SDK Exception: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required
> param "state" missing from persistent data.

I'll just follow and read the previous topic and comments above. And double check URL of Valid OAuth redirect URI.

Here's what id done. Well appreciated if you can share some thoughts and correct me..

**create-acc.php**

```
///FACEBOOK SIGNUP

session_start();
include_once 'config-facebook.php';

try {
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
 } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo "Response Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
  exit();
 } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo "SDK Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
  exit();
  }

 $redirectURL = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/create-acc.php";
 $permissions = ['email'];
 $fLoginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $permissions);


  $facebook_button ='

 <div style="background-color:white; color:#4b5563;    cursor:pointer;" class="inline-flex border-2 py-1.5 px-5 rounded text-lg border-gray-300">
         <div style="margin-top:5px;">
    <img style="width:25px;" src="./assets/apps/facebook-logo-2019.png"/>
 </div>
  <a href="'.$fLoginURL.'"  style="margin:5px 10px;"><b>Sign up with Facebook</b></a>
     </div>


         ';
```

**config-facebook.php**

```
include_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '**************',
'app_secret' => '*************',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'
  ]);


   $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
```

I'm literally new on this programming and still learning. So if you help it really save my time and learn on provided codes.And if I tried to add some callback codes to get a data, it looks like this on my work

**create-acc.php** add ons callback codes

```
///FACEBOOK SIGNUP

session_start();
include_once 'config-facebook.php';

if (isset($accessToken))
 {
if (!isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) 
{
    //get short-lived access token
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
    
    //OAuth 2.0 client handler
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
    
    //Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
    
    //setting default access token to be used in script
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
  } 
  else 
  {
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
}



if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{
    header('Location: ./');
}


 try {
    $fb_response = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email');
    $fb_response_picture = $fb->get('/me/picture?redirect=false&height=200');
    
    $fb_user = $fb_response->getGraphUser();
    $picture = $fb_response_picture->getGraphUser();
    
    $_SESSION['fb_user_id'] = $fb_user->getProperty('id');
    $_SESSION['fb_user_name'] = $fb_user->getProperty('name');
    $_SESSION['fb_user_email'] = $fb_user->getProperty('email');
    $_SESSION['fb_user_pic'] = $picture['url'];
    
    
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook API Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    session_destroy();
    
    header("Location: ./");
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
 } 
 else 
 {  


 $redirectURL = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/create-acc.php";
 $permissions = ['email'];
 $fLoginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $permissions);

     $facebook_button ='

 <div style="background-color:white; color:#4b5563;    cursor:pointer;" class="inline-flex border-2 py-1.5 px-5 rounded text-lg border-gray-300">
         <div style="margin-top:5px;">
    <img style="width:25px;" src="./assets/apps/facebook-logo-2019.png"/>
 </div>
  <a href="'.$fLoginURL.'"  style="margin:5px 10px;"><b>Sign up with Facebook</b></a>
     </div>


         ';

}
```

and the **config-facebook.php**

```
 session_start();
include_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';

 $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '************',
'app_secret' => '************',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'
  ]);


  $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper(); 

 try {
if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']))
    {$accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];}
else
    {$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();}
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook API Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
echo 'Facebook SDK Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
 }
```

and the **result** here

> Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data. in /www/wwwroot/fruitask.com/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php:244 Stack trace: #0 /www/wwwroot/fruitask.com/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(221): Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->validateCsrf() #1 /www/wwwroot/fruitask.com/config-facebook.php(20): Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getAccessToken() #2 /www/wwwroot/fruitask.com/create-acc.php(162): include_once('/www/wwwroot/fr...') #3 {main} thrown in /www/wwwroot/fruitask.com/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php on line 244

Please do share some thoughts or any alternative way I can implement Facebook login on my website using PHP. Thanks in advance