# Required param state missing from persistent data

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I've an issue with php-graph-sdk, I've those functions

```
 protected function getFacebook()
    {
        static $facebook = null;
        if($facebook == null){
            $facebook =  new Facebook\Facebook([
                'app_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                'app_secret' => $this->getAppSecret(),
                'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'
            ]);
        }
        return $facebook;
    }
```

```
public function getLoginUrl($url)
    {
        $fb = $this->getFacebook();
        
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        
        $autorisations = ['email']; 
        return $helper->getLoginUrl($url , $autorisations);
    }
```

```
 public function callback(&$error = null)
    {
        $fb = $this->getFacebook();
        
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        
        try {
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        } catch(Facebook\Exception\ResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            $error = 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        } catch(Facebook\Exception\SDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            $error = 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
        ....
  }
```

And I do

```
 $url = $Facebook->getLoginUrl(URL);
```

And in the callback file

```
$token = $Facebook->callback($error);
```

When I click on the link, the callback file is executed and  $helper->getAccessToken(); causes this error:
Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.

I've seen posts about that and no fix works for me

EDIT:
What I've found currently is that: [Facebook SDK error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684473/facebook-sdk-error-cross-site-request-forgery-validation-failed-required-param)
[Cross-site request forgery validation failed required param state missing from persistent data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419787/cross-site-request-forgery-validation-failed-required-param-state-missing-from-p)
and
https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/issues/1123
https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/issues/1134

Comment: You mention that you've seen posts about this, but no fixes work for you. To help the community avoid suggesting fixes you've already tried, can you edit your post to include the things you've already tried?

Comment: Can you check if the PHP session ID stays the same between before you send the user to the login dialog, and after when they got redirected back? It might be a problem with the session cookie’s `SameSite` attribute.

Comment: The session_id() is always 5a128v17bor5divgr3tiire56 before and after

Comment: session_get_cookie_params()["samesite"]: is ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved my issue by switching samesite to Lax by adding that in config.php
`ini_set('session.cookie_samesite','Lax');`